# SQL Server: how to insert to temporary table?

Tags: sql-server, insert, temp-tables

I have one Temporary Table

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (TEMP_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1))
```

And I would like to insert records to that table, How can I?I do as follow:

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP DEFAULT VALUES
```

But sometimes it doesn't work. What it might be?And I would like to know lifetime of temptable in SQL Server. Please Help me!

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean about "sometimes it doesn't work."

However, a local temp table (a single #) lifetime is the current session or scope (such as the stored proc or function duration). [CREATE TABLE on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) as a lot more with examples in the section "Temporary Tables"

Answer (score 2):

Works for me!

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (TEMP_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1))

--And I would like to insert records to that table, How can I?I do as follow:

INSERT INTO #TEMP DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #TEMP DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #TEMP DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #TEMP DEFAULT VALUES

select * from #TEMP
```

Gives:

```
TEMP_ID 
1
2
3
4
```

Keep in mind it needs to be the same "batch" or single query etc.

PK :-)

Comment: same connection/scope, not batch. You can have GO between CREATE TABLE and INSERT

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine.  Also `INSERT INTO #TEMP (TEMP_ID) VALUES (DEFAULT)`.  When you say that sometimes it doesn't work, what error are you getting?  # tables only have a lifetime and scope of your session.